# PHP Echo one result from list of many that matches a specific number

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The script is supposed to output a list of profiles who have a certain item in their backpack, for example item "125" At the moment this is the output:

```
Defindex: 125 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 56 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 60 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 115 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 170 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 182 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 140 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 261 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 278 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 277 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 266 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 295 - 76561197992146126
```

Full list at http://pastebin.com/G6bjzAwM.

Below is the desired output

```
Defindex: 125 - 76561197992146126
Defindex: 125 - 76561197995524521
Defindex: 125 - 76561197998542532
```

To do this all I need is a good IF function which will parse the results and IF (example) "125" then echo "Defindex: 125 - $profile"

```
  <?php
        $APIkey = 'MyAPIKey';
        $profile = '76561197992146126'; 
        $backpackURL = "http://api.steampowered.com/ITFItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=" . $APIkey . "&SteamID=" . $profile . "&format=json";
        $userBackpack = json_decode(file_get_contents($backpackURL), true);

        $result = $userBackpack['result'];
        $items = $result['items'];
        foreach($items['item'] as $ind=>$item) {
        $defindex = $item['defindex'];
        echo "Defindex: $defindex - $profile<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```

I can make the script loop through a file, so that's not a big deal.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I could also instead of anything special, if the script could parse with a true or false and echo $profile if true that would work as well...

Comment: hard to say without having API access

Comment: actually I revised the question, all I really need is a reasonably good IF then echo script. Any help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since you didn't give me any profiles to loop through I am going to assume you have that part figured out. For your foreach just use the code I have below.

```
foreach($items['item'] as $ind => $item) {
  if ($item['defindex'] == 125) {
    echo "Defindex: $defindex - $profile<br/>";
  }
}
```

Is there something else that you needed to do? This seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: yeah, it is pretty straightforward, I am just crap at building IF/Foreach codes. you removed the definition of defindex. Adding it back in after foreach fixed it. Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Yeah, I guess I missed that. You could have also written it like this: echo "Defindex: {$item['defindex']} - $profile<br/>";

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
foreach($items['item'] as $ind => $item) {
  if ($item['defindex'] == 125) {
    echo "Defindex: {$item['defindex']} - $profile<br/>";
  }
}
```

His works in theory, but in application he had a small issue

edit: did notice his comment, oh well incase someone forgets to read that, this is here.